# IBM Melbourne quantum computer performance and errors

Tags: ibm-q-experience, measurement, ibm-quantum-devices, error-mitigation

What is the reason for high variation in measurement probability results of a simple 3/4 qubit measurement circuit on IBM Melbourne machine in comparison with the same circuit being run on IBM Vigo/Santiago.

Variation in Vigo: approx. 0.7

Variation in Melbourne: approx. 2.6

Comment: Melbourne is a very old design compared to Vigo.

Answer (score 3):

There are many factors that going into this, but most of them are boiled down together into a metric that IBM called Quantum Volume (QV).

ibmq_vigo has a QV of 16:

[image: Snapshot of Vigo's QV from IBMQ Experience website]

Where as ibmq_16_melbourne as QV of 8:

[image]

You can read more about QV here: https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-quantum-hardware/measuring-quantum-volume.html